# How to change the input field status after form submit validation?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, validation, bootstrap-4

I'm wondering if there is a way to manually set valid or invalid status of the input field with JavaScript? I have input field that is used as a search field. Once user enter the value I will get response from the server I should mark if input value is correct or incorrect. So far I was able to do that until user clicks submit. Once user clicks on submit I can't change the status of the field. It's marked as valid and I still didn't find the way to change that with JavaScript.

Here is example:

```js
$('#save').on('click', saveFrm);

function saveFrm() {
  var form = $('#new-record');

  if (form[0].checkValidity() === false) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log('Invalid form data...');
  } else {
    console.log('Send Ajax Request');
  }

  form.addClass('was-validated');
}

$('#search_user').on('click', getUser);

function getUser() {
  var inputFld = $(this).parent().parent().children('input'),
    msgFld = inputFld.closest('div').find('.invalid-feedback'),
    saveBtn = inputFld.closest('form').find(':submit'),
    inputVal = inputFld.val(),
    regex = /^([0-9]{1,8})$/;
  
  if (inputVal) {
    if (regex.test(inputVal) === false) {
      saveBtn.prop('disabled', true);
      inputFld.addClass('is-invalid').val(''); // Apply
      msgFld.text('User ID has to be numeric 1-8 digits long.');
      setTimeout(function() {
        inputFld.removeClass('is-invalid').val('');
        msgFld.text('');
        saveBtn.prop('disabled', false);
      }, 5000);
    } else {
      console.log('Send Ajax Request...');
    }
  } else {
    inputFld.hasClass('is-invalid') ? inputFld.removeClass('is-invalid') : '';
    inputFld.addClass('is-valid');
  }

}
```

```css
#search_user {
  border-top-right-radius: 0.25rem !important;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0.25rem !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <form name="new-record" id="new-record" class="needs-validation" novalidate>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name">Name:</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" maxlength="120" placeholder="Enter the name." required>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">Please provide Name</div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-6">
        <label>Type:</label>
        <select class="custom-select browser-default" name="type" id="type" required>
          <option value="">--Select Type--</option>
          <option value="1">Level 1</option>
          <option value="2">Level 2</option>
          <option value="3">Level 3</option>
        </select>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">Please provide Type</div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group col-6">
        <label class="control-label" for="user_id">User ID:</label>
        <div class="input-group">
          <div class="input-group addon">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="user_id" id="user_id" value="" maxlength="8" placeholder="Enter User ID">
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" name="search_user" id="search_user"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
            </div>
            <div class="invalid-feedback"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 text-center">
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" name="save" id="save" value="Save">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

In the example try to click on Save button and then enter some invalid value in User ID field. Then if you click search button, message will show under the field but green is still appearing around the input field. I'm wondering if there is a way to work around this problem with JavaScript/JQuery?

Comment: What you can do is add a function inside the submit function to validate all fields before submitting it. If there is an error, then return false and it will stop the submission

Comment: @Keith Can you please provide example? I'm not sure that I understand completely your approach. Thank you.

Comment: From the markup you have, I recreated https://jsfiddle.net/mxqj6yup/ but it seems to validate correctly before the submit. Does user need to be validated?

Comment: @Keith User ID field is not required. If there is a value that has to be correct value that is populated from the ajax response. If not just leave the field blank. I hope this make sense.

Comment: OK then what you have works onChange, meaning once the user types something into the name field it validates, the same for the dropdown ( and changes the validation borders). So is there some other validation you need done before the submit? or is there something else that needs validation on server side?

Comment: @Keith All other fields int he form but User ID should be validated on the client side. User ID is exception since That value is already checked with the Ajax response. All I want is to prevent user of submitting invalid USER ID. Also, they should be able to see when the User ID is invalid. If you click Submit/Save form and then try to enter invalid ID and click search, User ID still remains green (valid) that is confusing. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You can send the UserId with the Ajax request to validate it ( in turn if it's false then return a message in JSON format to add to the validation field that needs to be fixed ).

```
if (form[0].checkValidity() === false) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  console.log('Invalid form data...');
} else {
  // When you send the request, add in the UserId used so it can get validated.
  console.log('Send Ajax Request');
  // If the validation is false, then add in the validation error here and return false in the function to stop it.     
}
```